# Flink - structuring job to maximize throughput

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have 4 types of kafka topics and 65 topics of each type. The goal is to do some simple windowed aggregation on the data and write it to a DB.

The topologies will look something like:

**kafka -> window -> reduce -> db write**

Somewhere in this mix I want / need to do a **union** - or possibly several (depending on how many topics are combined each time).

The data flow in the topics ranges from 10K to >200K messages / min.

I have a four node flink cluster with 30 cores / node. How do I build these topologies to spread the load out?

Comment: Quick question, to be sure and avoid confusion: Do you have in total 260 Kafka topics and each one with multiple partitions of its own, or 4 Kafka topics with each 65 partitions? Spread out would happen naturally in the latter case.

Comment: 260 topics with one partition each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am writing this answer assuming that each of the 65 topics of the same type contains the same type of data.

The simplest solution to this problem would be to change the Kafka setup such that you have 4 topics with 65 partitions each. Then you have 4 data sources in the program, with high parallelism (65) and this distributes across the cluster naturally.

If it is not possible to change the setup, I see two things you can do:

- One possible solution is to create a modified version of the FlinkKafkaConsumer where one source may consume multiple topics (rather than only multiple partitions of one topic). With that change, it would work pretty much as if you were using many partitions, rather than many topics. If you want to go with this solution, I would ping the mailing list to get some support for doing this. It would be a valuable addition to the Flink code anyways.
- You can give each source a separate resource group, which will give it a dedicated slot. You can do this via "env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer(...)).startNewResourceGroup();". But here, the observation is that you try to execute 260 distinct sources on a cluster with 120 cores (and thus probably 120 task slots). You would need to increase the number of slots to hold all the tasks.

I think the first option is the preferable option.

Comment: So if I go 'as-is' it will try to put all of them on the same machine? Unf changing the partitioning isn't an option.

Comment: Unless you specify the "startNewResourceGroup()", the scheduling will try to reuse existing resource groups, which may cause them to share the same machine. The Multi-Topic KafkaConsumer is the best bet then, in my opinion.

Comment: I will add support for reading from multiple topics with one FlinkKafkaConsumer https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-3102